# How to get value from dynamically generaged editfield in Blackberry

Tags: user-interface, blackberry, dynamic-ui, blackberry-editfield

I need to generate ui component dynamically at runtime. I am able to generate the component, but my problem is how to get value entered in dynamically generated field?

I am doing something like this.

```
    final HorizontalFieldManager hfm = new HorizontalFieldManager();

    for (int i=0; i<5; i++)
    {
        hfm.add(new EditField());
    }
```

Is there any way to set tag of field and later we could find control by tag?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I know, there is no way to set a unique id for an EditField. Maybe you can use a sub class of it, and implement your own unique id mechanism.
Or, as your HorizontalFieldManager holds nothing but EditField, you can get a field by position, and cast it to EditField. Like this:

```
Field f = hfm.getField(index);
EditField ef = (EditField)f;
```

UPDATE:

`public class MyEditField extends EditField {`

```
private int _id;

public MyEditField(int id) {
    _id = id;
}

public int getID() {
    return _id;
}
```

}

class MyHfm extends HorizontalFieldManager {

```
    //This is a cache, which holds all EditFields.
```

private IntHashtable    _editfields = new IntHashtable();

```
    public EditField getById(int id) {
        EditField ef = (EditField)_editfields.get(id);
        return ef;
}

    public void add(Field f) {
        super.add(f);
        if (f instanceof MyEditField) {
            _editfields.put(((MyEditField)f).getID(), f);
        }
    }

    public void delete(Field f) {
        super.delete(f);
        if (f instanceof MyEditField) {
            _editfields.remove(((MyEditField)f).getID());
        }
    }
```

}

And then you can do like this:

```
    MyHfm hfm = new MyHfm();
    hfm.add(new MyEditField(0));
    hfm.add(new MyEditField(1));
    //get the field with id
    EditField f = hfm.getById(1);
```

There are some other delete/add methods, remember to handle the cache inside them.

Comment: Can you please give some example of sub class to implement unique id mechanism?

Answer (score 3):

Use [Field.setCookie(Object)](http://www.blackberry.com/developers/docs/7.1.0api/net/rim/device/api/ui/Field.html#setCookie%28java.lang.Object%29) and [Field.getCookie()](http://www.blackberry.com/developers/docs/7.1.0api/net/rim/device/api/ui/Field.html#getCookie%28%29) to set and retrieve a cookie on the field.  You can use this to match up the edit field the way you want.

Answer (score 1):

```
EditField[] ef = new EditField[size];//at global in class
```

//Do something

```
VerticalFieldManager vfm = new VerticalFieldManager();
for(int i=0 ;i<size ;i++)
{
    HorizontalFieldManager hfm = new HorizontalFieldManager();
    ef[i] = new EditField();
    hfm.add(ef[i]);
    vfm.add(hfm);
}
add(vfm);
```

//complete Creating UI

// Start getting value from EditField

```
public void fieldChanged(Field field, int context) {
    super.fieldChanged(field, context);
    for(int i=0;i<size;i++)
    {
        if (field.equals(ef[i]) {
            system.out.println("Value from editfield :- " + ef[i].getText());
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I write this code in notepad so if there is any spelling mistake in code or error regarding spelling then please solve it.

Comment: Is there any way to set and get tag or id or name to the field so that value from specific field can be fetched?

Comment: @Ajmal Please be specific to the question.

Comment: @Krish i do not understand what you want to implement.
Please give brief description of your requirements.
What is tag,id or name ...???

Answer (score 1):

You can Try like this

```
Editfield ef = new Editfield();
add(ef);
ef.setcookie("Here you can set object with specific value");
ef.setchangelistner(this);
```

and in field change listner function

```
public void fieldChanged(Field field, int context) {
    object ob = field.getcookie();
    // compare this ob and give appropriate actionss
}
```